# Capture and display image with custom camera app

Tags: android, android-camera

It's bugging me for few days know. Problem is that I don't know if I'm going in right direction.

My starting activity is ImageDisplay class which calls startActivityForRestult for CustomCamera activity. After picture is taken user is returned to ImageDisplay and capture image should be displayed, but its not. What am I doing wrong?

Second thing, I guess its really important, at which point camera should be released?

ImageDisplay:

```
public class ImageDisplay extends Activity{

ImageView imageHolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.al_imagedisplay);
    imageHolder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomCamera.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  

        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("result");
        imageHolder.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}

}
```

CustomCamera:

```
public class CustomCamera extends Activity {

private Camera mCamera;
private NewItemSurfaceView mPreview;
Button captureButton;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
public static final String MY_CAMERRA_APP = "MyCameraApp";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.al_newitem_camera);

    captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new NewItemSurfaceView(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flCamera);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("Camera error",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }
        Log.i("Picture", pictureFile.toString());
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Camera error", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Camera error", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }



        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", pictureFile);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

    }

};

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
            "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.i("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify onActivityResult method like this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  

        String photoPath = (String) data.getExtras().get("result");
        imageHolder.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("photoPath"));
    }
}
```

Do some modification in your onPictureTaken method like this

```
 Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
```

Comment: This did the trick, I've just had to use getAbsolutePath instead of getAbsoluteFile (maybe you miss typed it). Still have few problems, displayed image is rotated and I can not find images on sd card... If you have some thoughts about that I'll appreciate it if not thanks anyway